# How to load data from database to Ehcache when the application starts

Tags: spring, ehcache

I want to load the data from database into cache memory using Spring ehCache when the application starts i.e when the server starts before any other method is called. I dont want to use a constructor.
Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what the `BootstrapCacheLoader` will do for you.

Have a look at the following [documentation entry](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/configuration/configuration#cache-warming-for-multi-tier-caches).

It seems this is fully integrated in the Spring Ehcache bridge - see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/ehcache/EhCacheFactoryBean.html#setBootstrapCacheLoader-net.sf.ehcache.bootstrap.BootstrapCacheLoader-)

In short the steps to get there are:

1. Determine how you will know what needs to be loaded at startup - that is your set of keys
2. Implement your own `BootstrapCacheLoader` that will use the set to load eagerly all entries, async or sync at cache initialisation time.
3. Wire it using a `BootstrapCacheLoaderFactory` through XML (Ehcache) or even directly (Spring)

Comment: how to check whether the data has been copied fram data source to ehChache. Where will the cache get stored? inside jvm? how to check what data is stored in ehCache.

Answer (score 3):

As @LouisJacomet mentioned you need to implement [BootstrapCacheLoader](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/2.9/net/sf/ehcache/bootstrap/BootstrapCacheLoader.html), this implementation is what will do your preloading. Since you are using Spring you will create a bean of the implemented class and call [EhCacheFactoryBean.setBootstrapCacheLoader](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/ehcache/EhCacheFactoryBean.html#setBootstrapCacheLoader-net.sf.ehcache.bootstrap.BootstrapCacheLoader-) so that the cache factory is aware of the loader.

Here is a link with a complete implementation.
https://javaglobin.wordpress.com/2013/11/13/declarative-caching-with-spring/

Have a look at **MyBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory** and also note that there is a  **EhCacheFactoryBean** bean that is called ehCacheFactory.

Comment: Thank @XaviLópez, I will elaborate

Comment: Yeah, the javaglobin entry is for Spring 3.1, and presupposes an ehcache.xml file is being used. How is it supposed to be done for Spring 4 with java config (and thus no ehcache.xml)? Seems to me `EhCacheManagerFactoryBean` does nearly nothing in a java config-only approach. Is the name `ehCacheFactory` "special"?