# Pre-populating a cache with Spring's JSR-107 annotations

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache, jcache

I have a table with often-read, rarely-changed records (about 50,000) that I need to cache. I'd like to pre-populate the cache at server startup time with a single query loading all records. I'm not sure what's the best way to do it when using Spring's [annotations](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-jsr-107). The only way I found apparent from the docs is to load all entities in one service method than pass them to a method in another service annotated with `@CachePut` and which doesn't do anything else.

```
PreloaderService:

@AutoWired
private CacheService cacheService;

public void getAllWidgets() {
  List<Widget> widgets = ... load them in one query
  for (Widget widget: widgets) {
    cacheService.populate(widget); //must call a different class so that it Spring's proxy for @CachePut gets used
  }
}


CacheService:

@CachePut
public void populate(@CacheValue Widget widget){
  //do nothing else, all we need is the caching annotations to be processed
}
```

The above doesn't appear very elegant to me but cannot see another way. By the way, I'm using Ehcache in case a lower-level API would achieve this.

Comment: I think this can be closed as a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26927044/how-to-load-data-from-database-to-ehcache-when-the-application-starts

Comment: Here is a blog with exactly what you want https://javaglobin.wordpress.com/category/spring/

Comment: Thanks @Leon, I had missed the other resources. You can put it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: nah, if you are happy with that other answer I will add the blog link to that and close this one as a duplicate