# Does EhCache's BootstrapCacheLoader pay attention to cache settings?

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I've implemented cache warming in EhCache using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26927044/2495717). Does EhCache's BootstrapCacheLoader <del>run</del> reload the cache every time it is called, or does it also check the cached data is stale before running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of the `BootstrapCacheLoader` is to run once at application startup to bring *known or identified* hot keys in memory.

What happens if you run it multiple times depends on its implementation.

Now if what you want is eager refresh of entries, you may instead want to look at [documentation for `RefreshAheadCache` or `ScheduledRefreshCacheExtension`](http://www.terracotta.org/documentation/4.1/bigmemorymax/api/refresh-ahead).

Comment: What I'm hoping to achieve is to avoid cache warming until the cache has expired. Multiple separate Java main classes run during the evening and the cache shouldn't be warmed by each of them.

Comment: I've been setting cache TTL to a day of seconds